# Куда ставить ударение в слове «недруг»?

Tags: орфоэпия

Куда ставить ударение в слове «недруг»? И почему?

Answer (score 3):

Если есть сомнения в постановке ударения в слове, то нужно обращаться к орфоэпическим словарям.

> Орфоэпия (от греч. *orthos* — «правильный» и *epos* —«речь») — это исторически сложившиеся нормы русского литературного произношения отдельных звуков и звукосочетаний в потоке устной речи.

Так заглянем в них.
В словаре "Русское словесное ударение" (М. В. Зарва): [**не́друг**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3), -а, *мн.* -и, -ов.
Во всех других орфоэпических словарях (под ред. Р. И. Аванесова; под ред. Н. А. Еськовой; О. А. Михайловой) ударение такое же.
Стоит заметить, что во всех формах ударение падает на "е" первого слога.

*Но ты велишь — я добрым стану снова

И ствол разящий в землю обращу.

Скажи мне только ласковое слово —

И я обиду не́другу прощу!*
Эдуард Асадов

Answer (score 0):

Нéдруг - это не "не друг"(посторонний человек), а враг. Не- это не отрицание дружбы, а утверждение недружбы - вражды, то есть. Хотя интернет отказывается фиксировать недружба как корректное слово, но недружба - это как нелюбовь или как ненависть. Сложно, когда логика интернета не совпадает с логикой твоего родного языка.

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке, в отличие от многих языков мира, ударение разноместное. Ударным может быть любой слог: первый ([мЕстностей](https://uchipravila.ru/udarenie/mestnostey)), второй ([намЕрение](https://uchipravila.ru/udarenie/namerenie)), третий ([дешевИзна](https://uchipravila.ru/udarenie/deshevizna)) и даже четвертый ([аэропОрты](https://uchipravila.ru/udarenie/aeroporty)). Конкретного правила, которое бы определяло принцип постановки ударения, нет, поэтому в большинстве случаев произношение приходится просто запоминать.

В слове «*н**е**друг*» ударение фиксированное, остается на приставке во всех падежах единственного и множественного числа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Куда ставить ударение в слове «недруг»?](https://uchipravila.ru/udarenie/nedrug)